# Not printing smartphp calendar events text in mozilla

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, printing

I am using smart php calendar in my application here i am using custom print for print background colors and hole calendar.

but when i print the calendar its working in google chrome but not working in mozilla..

here is my custom print code.

```
<script>
  function printPage(printpage1)
  {
   var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body><div style='-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;'>";
   var footstr = "</div></body>";
   var newstr1 = document.getElementById(printpage1).innerHTML;
   var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
   document.body.innerHTML = headstr+newstr1+footstr;
   window.print();
   document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
   location.reload();
   return false;
  }

</script>
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: The -webkit-print-color-adjust property is a non-standard CSS extension that can be used to force printing of background colors. It does not work in Firefox. In Mozilla you'll have to activate the option: File > Page Setup... > Print Background.

Comment: Hi Axel, i given print background option to Mozilla but i didnt get the text i am getting colors.both text and colors are printing in chrome.

Comment: You mean you only get the background in firefox? No text at all? Could you provide an example page?

Comment: Hi Axel.. u can see the images here.. http://mozillaimages.blogspot.in/ and waiting for ur great help..